# Flagging questions asking for code

Tags: feature-request, flags, scope, needs-more-focus

I'd like to suggest another flag for questions which asks for code implementation. The reason for this, there have been lots of question like this lately (at least on the tags I usually browse). Although you can often flag this kind of questions as "Too broad" or "Off topic" I feel like it should be a dedicated flag. So, when I stumble upon a guy asking:

"Hey, I'm new to Java and I want to create an Android game. Can you give me the code?"

I don't have to think if this question is "Too broad" or "Off topic" but just flag that as "Code request" or something and that will be all. Easy and quick.

That's my suggestion anyway.

Comment: *Flag this question as Off-Topic*